# Session only works one time spring mvc,

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

     @RequestMapping(value = "showLogin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public ModelAndView showLogin(HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session) {

     return new ModelAndView("login");
     }

    @RequestMapping(value = "login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String login(HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session) {

        String page = "login";
        String loginId = request.getParameter("loginId");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
    //  HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("USERNAME", loginId);

        if(loginId.equals("admin") && password.equals("admin")){
            session.setAttribute("loginId", "admin");
            session.setAttribute("userName", "admin");
            session.setAttribute("userDetails", "System Administrator");
            session.setAttribute("USERNAME", "admin");

            page = "home";
            return page;
        }
@RequestMapping(value = "projdet", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String project(
            @ModelAttribute("projMaster") ProjectMaster projMaster,
            Model model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session) {

        List<ProjectMaster> allProjectlist =getMasterDaoService().getAllProjList();
    model.addAttribute("Projlist", allProjectlist);

        String page = "project";
        return page;
    }
```

Session only works one time spring mvc,once login  returns home page but from home to next screen no user details and session not found in any other controller

Comment: It is not possible. Httpsession is available throughout application. You might have done session invalidate at some place

Comment: i know this Httpsession is available throughout application.Used only once...                                                                         @RequestMapping("logout")
 public String logout(HttpServletRequest request) {
  try {

   HttpSession session = request.getSession();
   session.invalidate();

  } catch (Exception ex) {
   ex.printStackTrace();
  }
  return "index";
 }

Comment: When you say no session is found, do you mean `HttpSession` is `null` ?

Comment: yes session is null...its avaliable at home page after login..but..on next screen/page its getting null

Answer (score 0):

I have a few suggestions:

1. This is probably not the root cause of the issue but your request mapping URL for the third controller function says "`projdet`".
2. Try debugging in Eclipse and stop at this line: `List<ProjectMaster> allProjectlist =getMasterDaoService().getAllProjList();
   model.addAttribute("Projlist", allProjectlist);`. Check the `session` variable thoroughly to see if it has the attributes you set on login
3. Add a log or sysout statement in the controller to display attributes that you had set.
4. Are you using Spring security? Is there any function that invalidates the session or calls `logout`?

While these may not point out the exact solution, it may help you figure out the issue. From what you have presented in the question, there is no evidence of anything wrong in the code.

Comment: thanks...i will work on it....its basically a high school level project no security is been used...like the third controller...call to any other controller..from home page... im not get any exception...but the session value is null..on pages...sysout value for String user=session.getattribute(userdetails).tostring ....is null...V r using bootstrap...and ajax...

Comment: Try `String user = (String) session.getAttribute("userDetails");`

Comment: yup tried both ways....String user=session.getattribute(userdetails).tostring........String user = (String) session.getAttribute("userDetails");......NULL...Exception...

Comment: You are only setting the attribute with name "userDetails" if the person logging in is the admin. Try looking for attribute with name "USERNAME".